# select aggregate function and all other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, teradata

How do I select all columns in a table and an aggregate function in a convenient way?

I.e. say that I have a table with 100 columns, and I want to send the following

```
SELECT Max(Columns 44), ALL OTHER COLUMNS
FROM zz
Group by ALL OTHER COLUMNS
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's no shortcut! (BTW, are you using MySQL or Teradata? Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: No need of group by if you want to select all column's value with aggregate function. Now, you just have to add in the select only :)

Comment: I think your way of doing things is optimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To select all columns from the table is:

```
select * from zz;
```

To select a maximum from the table is

```
select max(column44) from zz;
```

The two combined:

```
select zz.*, (select max(column44) from zz) as maxcol44
from zz;
```

If you want to omit column44 in your result rows and only have maxcol44, then you must list the columns:

```
select 
  column1, 
  column2, 
  ...
  column43, 
  (select max(column44) from zz) as maxcol44,
  column45, 
  ...
from zz;
```